# Enabling KIOSK mode using Samsung MDM 5.0 Knox

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, samsung-knox

I was trying to run the sample knox app using MDM 5.0 SDK. I am trying to implement KIOSK Mode/ Enable Camera/ Disable Camera but every time I run my app it throws me a security exception

```
01-02 00:56:07.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newkiosk/com.example.newkiosk.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Admin does not have android.permission.sec.MDM_KIOSK_MODE
```

In my manifest file I am declaring the uses permissions for all the operations but still not able to implement KIOSK Mode/ Enable Camera/ Disable Camera.

Do I need a license key or sign my app just like we do it for Google Maps or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable kiosk mode with MDM 5.0 Knox, you need:

- a knox license key to activate the API.
- the app must be a [Device Administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899443/how-can-my-app-access-admin-level-privileges-on-non-rooted-device/25899938#25899938) is a quick summary on how to make your a device administrator)

You must activate the license with this code:

```
EnterpriseLicenseManager.getInstance(context).activateLicense("<knox key here>");
```

Once the license is successfully activated, you can enable the kiosk mode with this call:

```
 KioskMode kioskMode = KioskMode.getInstance(context);
 kioskMode.enableKioskMode("<the package name of the kiosk app>");
```

To enable/disable camera you must use the DeviceRestrictionPolicy api:

```
EnterpriseDeviceManager enterpriseDeviceManager = new EnterpriseDeviceManager(context);
DeviceRestrictionPolicy deviceRestrictionPolicy = enterpriseDeviceManager.getDeviceRestrictionPolicy();
deviceRestrictionPolicy.setCameraState(false); //disable camera
```